# quadratic variation of process driven by brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

In the textbook *Introduction to Financial Derivatives*, the quadratic variation is defined as
$$
[g,g](t) := \lim_{\Delta t \to 0^+} \sum_0^t [g(t_{i+1}) - g(t_i)]
$$

and the author has just claimed that the quadratic variation of the (standard) Weiner process is linear.
$$
[W,W]_t = t
$$

Next, they suppose that if $\{X_t\}$ satisfies $d X_t = Y_t dt + Z_t dW_t$, where both $\{Y_t\}$ and $\{Z_t\}$ are adapted to $\{W_t\}$, then the quadratic variation of $\{X_t\}$ is given by
$$
d[X,X]_t = Z_t^2 dt
$$

Is there a proof for the last claim? My intuition is that the process generated by $Y_t dt$ is of bounded 1st variation.